# SQLLDR and .ctl files

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sql-loader, ctl

I have a ddl script to create some tables but the data is in .ctl files and I never use it before. I did some researches but I didn't quite understand how to use SQLLDR. How it works? Can I use some other way to execute the .ctl file? I'm just using PL/SQL and Oracle 10G

Comment: Refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/aload.htm. The post has examples that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you put it, it would go like this:

- using DDL script, create all those tables
- if CTL files contain data, I presume it is within the `BEGINDATA` section. Fine, couldn't be better because - as soon as you run the loader, it'll know where to find data to be loaded (it also means that control file uses `infile *`, right?)
- you have to have access to SQL*Loader

  - if you can connect to the database server, it is there
  - if you're using your own PC, see whether it is installed

    - along with the Client software
    - or, you might even have a database on your PC (XE?)
- once you have it (the `sqlldr.exe`), make sure its directory is contained with the `PATH` environment variable, or - if not - invoke it by specifying the whole path to it
- open command prompt of your operating system
- navigate to directory that contains `CTL` files
- run the loader as

  ```
  sqlldr scott/tiger control=file1.ctl log=file1.log
  ```

If everything is OK, data will be loaded. Check log files!